# Vuex - Computed property "name" was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, computed-properties

I have a component with some form validation. It is a multi step checkout form. The code below is for the first step. I'd like to validate that the user entered some text, store their name in the global state and then send then to the next step. I am using [vee-validate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate) and vuex

```html
<template>
<div>
    <div class='field'>
        <label class='label' for='name'>Name</label>
        <div class="control has-icons-right">

            <input name="name" v-model="name" v-validate="'required|alpha'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('name') }" type="text" placeholder="First and Last">
            <span class="icon is-small is-right" v-if="errors.has('name')">
                <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <p class="help is-danger" v-show="errors.has('name')">{{ errors.first('name') }}</p>

    </div>
    <div class="field pull-right">
        <button class="button is-medium is-primary" type="submit" @click.prevent="nextStep">Next Step</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        nextStep(){
            var self = this;

            // from baianat/vee-validate
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('addContactInfoForOrder', self);
                    this.$store.dispatch('goToNextStep');
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        name: function(){
            return this.$store.state.name;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have a store for handling order state and recording the name. Ultimately I would like to send all of the info from multi step form to the server.

```js
export default {
  state: {
    name: '',
  },

  mutations: {
    UPDATE_ORDER_CONTACT(state, payload){
      state.name = payload.name;

    }
  },

  actions: {
    addContactInfoForOrder({commit}, payload) {
      commit('UPDATE_ORDER_CONTACT', payload);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get an error that `Computed property "name" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

How do I bind the value from the name field to the global state? I would like this to be persistent so that even if a user goes back a step (after clicking "Next Step") they will see the name they entered on this step

Comment: In addition to Roy J's answer, it seems as if using `v-for` on a computed without a setter throws this warning as well.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

If you're going to `v-model` a computed, it needs a [setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). Whatever you want it to do with the updated value (probably write it to the `$store`, considering that's what your getter pulls it from) you do in the setter.

If writing it back to the store happens via form submission, you don't want to `v-model`, you just want to set `:value`.

If you want to have an intermediate state, where it's saved somewhere but doesn't overwrite the source in the `$store` until form submission, you'll need to create such a data item.

Comment: can you provide example of how to properly create a setter?

Comment: There's an example at the link in my post, and there's another at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58539133/392102)

Answer (score 69):

It should be like this.

In your **Component**

```js
computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
                nameFromStore: 'name'
            }),
        name: {
           get(){
             return this.nameFromStore
           },
           set(newName){
             return newName
           } 
        }
    }
```

In your **store**

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
         state:{
             name : "Stackoverflow"
         },
         getters: {
                 name: (state) => {
                     return state.name;
                 }
         }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old answer of yours, but why using a getter in this case ? Why not return this.nameFromStore from mapState ? It works just as well apparently.

Comment: @Jake For this given example what you are saying is right. But when you want to manipulate the saved data in the store then you can do that inside getter but if you using `this.nameFromStore` directly then you can't manipulate the data.

Answer (score 10):

For me it was changing.

```js
this.name = response.data;
```

To what computed returns so;

```js
this.$store.state.name = response.data;
```

Comment: This is working for me too. - assign data to another variable and then add to store function as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I've had such an error when getting value from the `store`, in `computed`, via `...mapState(['sampleVariable'])`, as you. Then I've used the `this.sampleVariable` in `<script>` and `sampleVariable` in `<template>`.

What fixed the issue was to `return` this in `data()`, assign it to a separated variable, and reuse across the `component` the newly created variable, like so:

```
data() {
  return {
    newVariable: this.$store.state.sampleVariable,
  }
}
```

Then, I've changed references in the component from `sampleVariable` to `newVariable`, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your computed property haven't yet using setter method while you're trying to set a new value to its property

your existing computed

```
computed: {
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }
}
```

then somehow you assign value to its computed property:

```
this.fullName = "new value"
```

this will produce error --> Vuex - Computed property "fullName" was assigned to but it **has no setter**

So you have to set Setter and Getter to your computed property

```
computed: {
  fullName: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      var names = newValue.split(' ')
      this.firstName = names[0]
      this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ImanShafiei ok, have just modified it

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exact same error

> Computed property "callRingtatus" was assigned to but it has no setter

here is a sample code according to my scenario

```
computed: {

callRingtatus(){
            return this.$store.getters['chat/callState']===2
      }

}
```

I change the above code into the following way

```
computed: {

callRingtatus(){
       return this.$store.state.chat.callState===2
    }
}
```

> ***fetch values from vuex store state instead of getters inside the computed hook***