# Switch Vuetify navigation drawer to mini and then temporary

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a project in Vue.js and I am using Vuetify. I have a toolbar and navigation drawer. What I would like is when on desktop the drawer is open. If the user clicks the side-icon the drawer switches to mini.

If on md the drawer switches to mini. if the user clicks the side-icon the mini switches back to drawer

If on sm or lower the navigation drawer switches to temporary

I have most of the pieces but I am getting an error when I click the side-icon. `Computed property 'mini' was assigned to but it has no setter.`

Here is my code:

```html
<v-toolbar 
    :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
    :app="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
    :fixed="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
    flat 
    fixed
    :scroll-toolbar-off-screen="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"
    :scroll-threshold="50">

    <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="mini = !mini">
    </v-toolbar-side-icon>

    <v-toolbar-title class="text-uppercase">
        <span class="font-weight-light">LOGO</span>
    </v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="">
        <v-btn icon v-for="item in menu" :key="item.icon">
            <v-icon>{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>

<v-navigation-drawer 
    clipped 
    :mini-variant="mini"
    v-model="drawer"
    :permanent="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdOnly"
    :temporary="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"
    app
    hide-overlay>

    <v-list dense>
        <v-list-tile
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
        >
            <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>

            <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I have created a codepen with what I have so far:

https://codepen.io/jsd219/pen/gJJMPQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a computed property to itself:

```
@click.stop="mini != mini"
```

You really don't want to do that. To find out why, you want to read on JS setters and getters.

If you want `mini` to be the computed which determines if your `<navigation-drawer>` is minified or not, use two separate placeholders for your info:

- one for whether the menu is forcefully opened (call it `menuOpen`), initially defined in `data()`, as `false` and then overwritten by your `@click.stop="menuOpen != menuOpen"`
- and one coming from `$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp`. Call it `mdAndUp`.

So your `mini` becomes:

```
  mini() {
    return !(this.mdAndUp|| this.menuOpen);
  }
```

See it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYYbwE?editors=1010).

Comment: This is close. the goal is on desktop the menu is open and the side-icon switches it to mini. on md size devices the menu switches to mini and the side-icon switches it back to open and finally on sm and xs devices the menu closes and converts to temporay. when the side-icon is clicked the menu opens

Comment: right now when the screen size goes to md the menu does not switch to mini. FYI: I changed `menuOpen: true,` in the data object

Comment: That's simple JavaScript logic and you can do it yourself. I told you what the underlying problem was (you were trying to assign to a getter). I'm here to help you learn, but I'm not available for hire. Besides, considering the complexity level of your code, your request is now way within your reach. IMHO, you'll learn more from taking it on yourself from here. If you still don't have it working by tomorrow, I'll get back and help you with anything you find too challenging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to modify the computed property `mini`.

To mutate a computed property, you would need to provide a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter):

```
computed: {
    mini: {
        get() {
           // get logic
        },
        set(value) {
           // set logic
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, your computed property `mini` returns true or false if based on `$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown`. You would need to include a new variable, something like `overwriteBreakpoint` and use that in your setter.

```
data() => ({
    overwriteBreakpoint: true
}),
computed: {
    mini: {
        get() {
           return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown || this.overwriteBreakpoint;            
        },
        set(value) {
           this.overwriteBreakpoint = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/dormenog/pen/MddbMY?editors=1011

**Update:**

To make this work on multiple screen sizes you'll need to come up with defined rules on when each prop of your nav bar should be `true` or `false`. This will become very messy, very quickly, and the benefit of the keeping track of the state is not really valuable because the screens will not change size in real time on the user's device.

I would advice separating the contents of your navbar into a component and wrap it with multiple `<v-navigation-drawer />` that will only be rendered by vue if the screen size is correct. This can be achieved using `v-if` and `v-else`.

Comment: I actually just added that right before you posted. :) I no longer get the error but when I click on the side-icon nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: can I no longer use: `@click.stop="mini = !mini` on the side-icon? the computed property works if the screen size changes but not on the click action

Comment: Reload and check again :). Its fixed

Comment: ok this is awesome! it's almost fully functioning. now the navigation never goes back to drawer when the screen size changes